# Django REST Framework (DRF): Set current user id as field value

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have model NewsModel and 2 serializers for him:

**models.py**

```
class NewsModel(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField('Заголовок', max_length=255, help_text='Максимальная длина - 255 символов')
    announce = models.TextField('Анонс', help_text='Краткий анонс новости')
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, help_text='Автор новости', related_name='news')
    full_text = models.TextField('Полный текст новости', help_text='Полный текст новости')
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('Дата публикации', auto_now_add=True, default=timezone.now, help_text='Дата публикации')

    def comments_count(self):
        return NewsComment.objects.filter(news=self.id).count()

    def get_author_full_name(self):
        return self.author.get_full_name()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'news'
        ordering = ('-pub_date',)
```

**serilizers.py:**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import NewsModel
from extuser.serializers import UserMiniSerializer

class NewsReadSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    author = UserMiniSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = NewsModel
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'announce', 'comments_count', 'reviews', 'author_name')

    def get_author_full_name(self, obj):
        return obj.get_author_full_name()


class NewsWriteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def validate_author(self, value):
        value = self.request.user.id
        return value

    class Meta:
        model = NewsModel
```

I select serializers in the **api.py**:

```
class NewsList(ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = NewsModel.objects.order_by('-pub_date')
    def get_serializer_class(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.request.method == 'GET':
            return NewsReadSerializer
        return NewsWriteSerializer

    class Meta:
        model = NewsModel
```

But when I will create NewsModel item, I see *Error 400: Bad request [{'author': 'This field is required'}]*

How I can set current user id as NewsItem.author value on creating new item?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In DRF version prior 3 field must be declader with allow_null=True and default=None. DRF don't run checking fields without this params. Result code:

```
class NewsReadSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    """
    Serializer only for reading.

    author field serialized with other custom serializer
    """

    author = UserMiniSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = NewsModel
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'announce', 'comments_count', 'reviews', 'author', 'pub_date',)


class NewsWriteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    """
    Serializer for creating and updating records.

    author here is the instance of PrimaryKeyRelatedField, linked to all users
    """

    author = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        queryset=User.objects.all(), # Or User.objects.filter(active=True)
        required=False, 
        allow_null=True, 
        default=None
    )

    # Get the current user from request context
    def validate_author(self, value):
        return self.context['request'].user

    class Meta:
        model = NewsModel      
        fields = ('title', 'announce', 'full_text', 'author',)
```

Answer (score 34):

I don't think you're using the serializer properly. A better practice to set request related data is to override `perform_create` in your view:

```
def perform_create(self, serializer):
    serializer.save(author=self.request.user)

def perform_update(self, serializer):
    serializer.save(author=self.request.user)
```

and then set your author serializer to read-only:

```
author = UserMiniSerializer(read_only=True)
```

this way you can simply use one single `NewsSerializer` for both read and write actions.

Comment: Alternatively, you can just omit `author` field in serializer completely. It gets saved anyway.

Comment: Wow - thank you! - it's the way it should be done - especially when extending generic/model viewsets. It seems obvious, but it wasn't for me. (there is really a lot of crappy solutions "out there", that include request.data modification.)

Comment: How do I do it with ListAPIView?

Answer (score 14):

In new DRF you can write

```
owner = serializers.HiddenField(
    default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault()
)
```

See http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#currentuserdefault

Comment: Note that if you want the field to be returned to users, you can instead use PrimaryKeyRelatedField and set read_only=True

Answer (score 5):

I would try something like this:

**your models.py**

```
class NewsModel(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(
        'Заголовок', max_length=255,
        help_text='Максимальная длина - 255 символов')
    announce = models.TextField('Анонс',
        help_text='Краткий анонс новости')
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        help_text='Автор новости', related_name='news')
    full_text = models.TextField(
        'Полный текст новости',
        help_text='Полный текст новости')
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(
        'Дата публикации', auto_now_add=True,
        default=timezone.now, help_text='Дата публикации')

def comments_count(self):
    return NewsComment.objects.filter(news=self.id).count()

def get_author_full_name(self):
    return self.author.get_full_name()

class Meta:
    db_table = 'news'
    ordering = ('-pub_date',)
```

**serializers.py**

(ref.: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#currentuserdefault)

```
from <yourapp>.models import NewsModel
from rest_framework import serializers


class NewsModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    author = serializers.HiddenField(default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault())
    class Meta:
        model = NewsModel
```

Also you should set **settings.py** to something like this:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',)
}
```

Comment: I think it is best aproach, then other (and, we no need set field null=True). And if we want not User, we must use set_context http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#using-set_context in class-based validator http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#class-based. see serializers.CurrentUserDefault sources

Comment: This solution make the most amount of sense, thank you!

Comment: Love you. This is what finally worked for me.